# How to match the patterns in java with assert J for below string

Tags: java, selenium, assert

I have a string like this

```
String xyz ="JAVAxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   ID: 123678   VERSION: 3"
```

and I want to know how I can verify that it conforms to aspecific pattern.

I do the assertion like this

```
assertThat(xyz).containsPattern("[A-Za-z]* ID: [0-9]* VERSION: [0-9]* ");
```

Comment: Your pattern has an extra space on the end. (Or your input string is missing a space on the end).

Comment: No extra space at the end

Comment: what's that gap between the `*` and the `"` then?

Comment: actually buy mistake i put the gap in code. But after "JAVAxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 3 white space. and "ID:" 1 white space "123678" after this 3 white space "VERSION:" 1 white space and "3"

Comment: Use this: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To build on the answer of stevecross, note that the suggested expression is pretty lenient. For example, it will match this:

```
String xyz =" ID: VERSION: "
```

You can be more strict in your matching if needed. Say, if you need to ensure non-blank words, use + instead of * like this:

```
assertThat(xyz).matches("[A-Za-z]+ +ID: [0-9]+ +VERSION: [0-9]+");
```

And if you need to have exactly three spaces between the key-value pairs, then add `{3}` to a class of characters including only space (`[ ]`), like this:

```
assertThat(xyz).matches("[A-Za-z]*[ ]{3}ID: [0-9]*[ ]{3}VERSION: [0-9]*");
```

I find online regex evaluators helpful. See for example this one: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks that one looks more professional and meaning full

Comment: Thanks @SnehalThakkar. Consider revising your question to make clearer what exactly you wanted to know and vote/accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you are looking for is `matches()`. Additionally your regex does not match the given string. The string contains multiple spaces between the 'blocks'. Thus you need to specify that in the regex:

```
assertThat(xyz).matches("[A-Za-z]* +ID: [0-9]* +VERSION: [0-9]*");
```

Comment: Yeah, because the string does not match.